# Mutex lock either hangs or doesn't work

Tags: c, locking, pthreads, mutex

I'm using pthreads to create a child process alongside the parent process. I'm trying to use mutex to stop after the first print statement in the child process and resume after the second print statement in the parent process:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

void *print(void *attr)
{
printf("I am the child process\n");
pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &lock);
printf("The child process is done\n");
pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
return 0;
}

int main()
{

pthread_t child;
pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
printf("I am the parent process\n");
pthread_create(&child, NULL, print, NULL);
pthread_join(child, NULL);
printf("The parent process is done\n");
pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
return 0;
}
```

The original output is as follows:

```
I am the parent process
I am the child process
The child process is done
The parent process is done
```

The output I'm looking for is as follows:

```
I am the parent process
I am the child process
The parent process is done
The child process is done
```

I can't for the life of me figure out how to achieve this with mutex, the closest I've come is for it to reach the first two statements before hanging indefinitely. I've also had the original output, as if the mutex statements are doing nothing.

Could anyone help me figure this out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Parent lock the mutex and waits in a join, and child waits on the locked mutex. How is this not a deadlock?

Comment: I've tried many other ways and they've all ended in a hang or no change to the output, this is only one of the ways I approached it.
What can I do to avoid the deadlock? What am I doing wrong to run into these issues?

Comment: wouldn't the usage of word thread be appropriate in entire discussion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need better signaling between the parent and child threads. This should do it:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t  cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
int             child_done = 0;
int             parent_done = 0;

void *print(void *attr)
{
    printf("I am the child process\n");
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    child_done = 1;
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond); // Because this thread also waits
    while (!parent_done)
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &lock);
    printf("The child process is done\n");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t child;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    printf("I am the parent process\n");
    pthread_create(&child, NULL, print, NULL);
    while (!child_done)
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &lock);
    printf("The parent process is done\n");
    parent_done = 1;
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    pthread_join(child, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Steve! I can see where I was going wrong now, makes a lot more sense. :)